# Game of Life Android Java

Tags: java, android, conways-game-of-life

I am having trouble with the game of life, my generations are going through but it is doing it incorrectly. I have a generate class which holds the rules of the game and the movement through the generations. A RunActivity which makes the movements through and sends it to a myView class which receives new a 2d array and "paints" it to the screen. MyView has two setPoint methods, one adds points to a 2d array based on a 2d array from gen class, and another which adds points based on touch motions There is also an ontouchlistener which adds a arraylist of points to the generation and a main activity which gets settings for game of life. Here is my most relevant code:

```
package com.example.gameoflife;


public class Generate {
    int dim;
    int[][] gena;
    int[][] genb;
    int a;
    //public static int[][] genc;


public Generate(int size){
    this.dim = size;
    this.gena = new int[dim][dim];
    this.genb = new int[dim][dim];
    //this.genc = new int[d][d];
}

public boolean birth(int parent, int neighbors){
    //rules for game of life
    if ((parent == 0)&&(neighbors ==  3))
        return true;
    if ((parent > 0)&&((neighbors == 3)||(neighbors == 2)))
        return true;
    return false;
}
public void grow(){
    //puts genb in gena after printing, clears genb
    for(int r = 0; r < dim; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < dim; c++){ 
            gena[r][c] = genb[r][c];   
        }
    }  
}

public void random(){
    //randomly fills object with life
    for(int r = 0; r<gena.length; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<dim;c++){
            gena[r][c] = (int) (Math.random()*2);
        }
    }
}

public void makelove(){
    //nested loop to determine where the cell is, and if it will live in the next generation

    for(int r = 0; r<dim; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c<dim; c++){
            a = 0;
            for (int i = r-1; i <= r+1; i++){
                for (int j = c-1; j <= c+1; j++){
                    if((i >= 0)&&(i < dim)&&(j >= 0)&&(j < dim)&&((i!=r)&&(j!=c))){
                        if (gena[i][j] > 0)                     
                        a++;    
                    }
                }
            }
        if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
            genb[r][c]++;
        else
            genb[r][c] = 0;


            //topleft
//          if ((r == 0)&&(c == 0)){
//                a = (gena[r+1][c] + gena[r+1][c+1] + gena[r][c+1]);
//                    if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                      genb[r][c]++;
//                    else
//                      genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
//            //topmid
//            else if ((r == 0)&&((c !=0)&&(c != (gena.length-1)))){
//                a = (gena[r][c-1] + gena[r+1][c-1] + gena[r+1][c] + gena[r+1][c+1] + gena[r][c+1]);
//                if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                  genb[r][c]++;
//                else
//                  genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
//            //topright
//            else if ((r == 0)&&(c == (gena.length-1))){
//                a = (gena[r][c-1] + gena[r+1][c-1] + gena[r+1][c]);
//                if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                  genb[r][c]++;
//                else
//                  genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
//            //rightmid
//            else if ((r != 0)&&(r!= (gena.length-1))&&(c == (gena.length-1))){
//                a = (gena[r-1][c] + gena[r-1][c-1]+ gena[r][c-1] + gena[r+1][c-1] + gena[r+1][c]);
//                if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                  genb[r][c]++;
//                else
//                  genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
//            //rightbottom
//            else if ((r == (gena.length-1))&&(c == (gena.length-1))){
//                a = (gena[r][c-1] + gena[r-1][c-1]+ gena[r-1][c]);
//                if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                  genb[r][c]++;
//                else
//                  genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
//            //bottommid
//            else if ((r == (gena.length-1))&&(c != 0)&&(c != (gena.length-1))){
//                a = (gena[r][c-1] + gena[r-1][c-1]+ gena[r-1][c] + gena[r-1][c+1] + gena[r][c+1]);
//                if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                  genb[r][c]++;
//                else
//                  genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
//            //leftbottom
//            else if((c == 0)&&(r == (gena.length-1))){
//                a = (gena[r-1][c] + gena[r-1][c+1]+ gena[r][c+1]);
//                if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                  genb[r][c]++;
//                else
//                  genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
//            //Left mid
//            else if((c == 0)&&(r != 0)&&(r != (gena.length-1))){
//                a = (gena[r-1][c] + gena[r-1][c+1]+ gena[r][c+1] + gena[r+1][c+1] + gena[r+1][c]);
//                if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                  genb[r][c]++;
//                else
//                  genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
//            //midmid
//            else{
//                a = (gena[r][c+1] + gena[r][c-1]+ gena[r-1][c-1] + gena[r-1][c+1] + gena[r-1][c] + gena[r+1][c] + gena[r+1][c-1] + gena[r+1][c+1]);
//                if (birth(gena[r][c], a))
//                  genb[r][c]++;
//                else
//                  genb[r][c] = 0;
//            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

The blocked code is another version i was trying which didn't work either but was having a different affect.

```
package com.example.gameoflife;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class RunActivity extends Activity {
    private MyView myView;
    protected float xTouchPosition = 0;
    protected float yTouchPosition = 0;
    protected int dimension;
    static int d;
    protected int size;
    private final static String TAG = "ThreadingMainActivity";
    private int mDelay = 2000;
    int array[] = new int[5];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //creates and sets view, receives and sets settings of GOF from main activity, creates life object, loops an execute thread
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        myView = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(myView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int[] array = extras.getIntArray("numbers");
        dimension = array[0];
        if (mDelay != 0)
        mDelay = (array[1] * 1000);
        myView.setDimension(dimension);
        setContentView(myView);
        myView.setOnTouchListener(new Listener(myView));
        Generate life = new Generate(dimension);
        life.random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            new run().execute(life);        
    }

    private class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View MyView, MotionEvent event){
        boolean returnValue = false;
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            xTouchPosition = event.getX();
            yTouchPosition = event.getY();
            System.out.println("The coordinates are x: " + xTouchPosition + " and y: " + yTouchPosition);
            returnValue = true;
            //myView.setPoints(xTouchPosition, yTouchPosition);
            myView.invalidate();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    }

    private class run extends AsyncTask<Generate, Generate, Generate> {
        //creates a new dimension and prints it
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Generate doInBackground(Generate... resId) {
            // creates a new generation of the life object
            Generate life = resId[0];
            sleep();
            life.makelove();
            life.grow();
            return life;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Generate result) {
            //displays the new generation of life object
            Generate life = (Generate) result;
            myView.setPoints(life.gena);
            myView.invalidate();
        }

        private void sleep() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(mDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have toyed with this code ssoooo much and could not figure it out. Thanks again for any help

Comment: I see good comments and questions here, but having all the code in place will really limit down the number of people that will actually read all the way through and provide an answer.  Can you narrow the code down to where your issues are?

Comment: Thank you, I have shortened it to what is more relevant.

Comment: In your grow() function you are not clearing genb. If you are new to programming/Java/Android, you might want to get your code working outside of Android first as a basic Java program then migrate it over to Android so that you can known working starting point. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I was using B to keep track of how long they have been alive to give it a color coding. What you mentioned worked so I found another method to keep track of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you count the middle cell? The middle cell must **not** be counted. From  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life):

> ... Every cell interacts with its **eight** neighbours, which are the
>   cells that are horizontally, vertically, or diagonally adjacent. ...

But, if you do not count the middle cell, can you post a screenshot?